# MAC OS - AppleScript - How to make it show username and password dialog once?

Tags: macos, shell, applescript, sudo

**Hello,**

In my AppleScript I am running the following code,

```
do shell script "sudo networksetup -setproxybypassdomains Ethernet *.local, 169.254/16"
do shell script "sudo networksetup -setwebproxy Ethernet 127.0.0.1 8888"
do shell script "sudo networksetup -setsecurewebproxy Ethernet 127.0.0.1 8888"
```

However, it asks to enter password every time. I mean when the script is opened it asks for password 3 times for each line of process. In order to prevent from asking password I have to type the following in the Terminal,

> sudo chmod u+s /usr/sbin/networksetup

When the Enter key is pressed it asks for the password and once entered and run the AppleScript then it doesn't ask for password (3 times) anymore.

But the user has to go to Terminal and type the above command. In order to prevent this I used the following code in the AppleScript,

```
do shell script "sudo chmod u+s /usr/sbin/networksetup"
```

So the user runs the AppleScript and it will auto set. But I get the following error message,

[image]

How to change the AppleScript for,

```
do shell script "sudo chmod u+s /usr/sbin/networksetup"
```

...to make it ask for password once and then execute the rest of the "...do shell script..." parts without asking for passwords. Or add the password along with the above line of code to make it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you looked at the definition for the "do shell script" command? You don't use sudo with that command. You would use "with administrator privileges" and you can supply a "user name" and "password" if you wish.

Do this... open AppleScript Editor. Under the File menu choose "open dictionary". Select StandardAdditions.osax from the dialog window. In the search field of the dictionary search for "do shell script" to see everything that you can do with that command.

For example, here's how you could use it. Good luck.

```
do shell script "networksetup -setproxybypassdomains Ethernet *.local, 169.254/16" with administrator privileges
```

Comment: +1, but the example command you chose is the very command that is not needed (and should never be used for security reasons) when your - correct - approach is used.

Comment: Agreed mklement0... I changed the example. I wasn't really focussed on what the example code was actually doing!

Comment: I did not have a chance to check this since the program I am working on is complex and this needs to be added in between. But will check this week. Thanks. It looks like your solution will be correct "regulus6633".

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the password as a parameter to the `sudo`. From the man page:

```
-S          The -S (stdin) option causes sudo to read the password from
                   the standard input instead of the terminal device.  The
                   password must be followed by a newline character.
```

Answer (score 0):

New answer to old question, but since no answer included both retention of the name & password plus proper hiding of the password during entry, this may help someone drawn to the question. This does both, and then uses name & password in a shell script similar(enough) to the OP's. The name & password are stored as properties of the script, but remain invisible. They are automatically "erased" if the script changes, and will need to be reentered for only the first run. If name or password are incorrect, then the script exits gracefully before continuing to any following code. "sudo" is not needed in a shell script, as long as it is run "with administrator privileges". Normally, just running "with administrator privileges" will force a pop-up to ask for name & password. But since they are already included in this example, the script silently applies the stored name & password, and no pop-up occurs after the first run.

```js
----------ENTER NAME & PASSWORD ONCE*----------
property admin : null --resets to null after each edit*
property pswrd : null --resets to null after each edit*
#--#--#--NOT A SECURE WAY TO STORE PASSWORDS!--#--#--#
repeat
    try
        if admin is null then set admin to (text returned of (display dialog "Enter username:" default answer "")) --get name.
        if pswrd is null then set pswrd to (text returned of (display dialog "Enter password for " & admin & ":" default answer "" with hidden answer)) --get pw.
        do shell script "whoami" user name admin password pswrd with administrator privileges --test name & pw.
        exit repeat --name & pw were OK!
    on error err
        set {admin, pswrd} to {null, null}
        if err is "User canceled." then return err
        display dialog err with icon 0
    end try
end repeat
--beyond this line, admin-name & password are retained in the admin & pswrd properties!
----------EXAMPLE OF NAME & PASSWORD USEAGE----------
do shell script "networksetup -listallhardwareports" user name admin password pswrd with administrator privileges
```

Comment: Yes, regular scripts store properties and global variables _in the file_, which are readily visible (especially if you use obvious names such as `admin` and `pswrd`).  Best practice is to never place sensitive information in scripts at all.  Note that multiple shell script statements can be performed in a single `do shell script with administrator privileges`.

Comment: By using "null" as the value for both admin and pswrd, the actual password is never seen in the script (and therefor not "readily visible"). Once the script is saved and run, the properties are entered via the pop-up-dialog but never seen in the file once entered. So, If you open up the file after entering your password, it still says "null". No password is recorded there.

Comment: I have tried before to reveal a property-value after entering it into an applescript file like the one posted, but I have never been able to uncover whatever that "encrypted" value is. Apparently that's why apple made those options like that. If someone thinks they can enter a value for the pswrd property of the script I posted, and then open it to see a password - good luck, and please show your work. It could be re-written to reveal a password- of course. But it is written to hide the password - that's the point.

Comment: So for any nubes- DO NOT change "null" to an actual password. Leave it as "null" and then only enter a password into the dialog box when running the script. There is no way to ever see the password that way. At least that I know of.

Comment: Also, the OP asked for a one-time password entry code(which this is) but that means that the script can be used by anyone who has access to the script once the password is entered. They won't be able to see your password but they don't need to because the administrator privileges remain unlocked for that shell script. That's the real threat here. A reset-timer would be good practice - but I stuck to the question as asked.

Comment: An easy example is to run your script and save it, then in another script use something like `set test to load script (choose file)` to load the script, where getting values will then be as simple as a statement like `log test’s pswrd`.  You might then think that saving the script as run-only or obfuscating the property name will be OK, but the script can still be loaded, and property and variable names are still visible in the compiled script (load it into a text editor, for example).  There are also script disassemblers, for example https://github.com/SentineLabs/aevt_decompile.

Comment: red_menace is correct. His method clearly reveals the stored password!

Comment: I've amended the script with a warning. Good call red_menace!